# Create HTML based on number in array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-binding-handlers

first time using KO, apologies for what may sound like a silly question.

I have an array full of data. One value is 'stars', which is a number. In my HTML, I would like to create HTML elements based on that value. For example, if the value is four, I would like 4 elements. If the value is 5, I would like 5 elements and so on. I have the rest of the data binding correctly, this is the one part I'm unsure of.

The element I would like to have duplicated is the 'fas fa-star`

**Data**

```
scores: [
    {
        title: 'Score One',
        stars: 5,
    },
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="scores" data-bind="foreach: scores">
    <li>
       <div class="title" data-bind="text: title"></div>
       <div class="stars">
           <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
       </div>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=custombindings  (step 4 in this tutorial).

Comment: Thanks. Not really sure how they relates to my layout structurel. If it helps, all my stuff is hard coded. It's not going to change from a database or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to set the value of class to the value of stars (like `<div class="5">`), then the following should work:

```
<ul class="scores" data-bind="foreach: scores">
    <li>
       <div class="title" data-bind="text: title"></div>
       <div data-bind="attr: { class: stars }">
           <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
       </div>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

**EDIT:**
Upon re-reading your question, this would be what you're looking for:

```
<ul class="scores" data-bind="foreach: scores">
    <li>
       <div class="title" data-bind="text: title"></div>
       <div data-bind="foreach: new Array(stars)"> // <-- replaced scores with stars
           <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
       </div>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm afraid that still only provided one star element instead of 5 (if we're referring to the data in my example)

Comment: my bad, updated the answer that should work.. working jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/47927/

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you for the effort! That's much appreciated!